# Creating the topic rule does not create the trigger on the lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, iot, terraform-provider-aws

This issue looks very much like a bug but I believe there must be something wrong in my terraform file because I can't find anybody on the web having the same problem.

Here is the part of my terraform file that creates a lambda and a topic rule for it:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "rds_persist" {
  filename         = "${local.rds_persist_file_path}"
  function_name    = "RdsPersist-${var.env}"
  role             = "${aws_iam_role.lambda_role.arn}"
  handler          = "package.handler"
  source_code_hash = "${local.rds_persist_package_hash}"
  runtime          = "nodejs8.10"
  memory_size      = 128
  timeout          = 10

  vpc_config = {
    subnet_ids         = ["${var.private_subnet_ids}"]
    security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.all_vpc_access.id}"]
  }

  environment {
    variables = {
      DB             = "${var.database_url}"
      IOT_DEVICE_ARN = "${var.iot_device_v1_sns_arn}"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iot_topic_rule" "rds_push" {
  name        = "${var.env}_RdsPush"
  description = "Pushes events to a persistence lambda (rds store)"
  enabled     = true
  sql         = "SELECT * as payload, topic() as topic, timestamp() AS timestamp FROM '#' WHERE startswith(clientid(), '${var.env}-')"
  sql_version = "2016-03-23"

  lambda {
    function_arn = "${aws_lambda_function.rds_persist.arn}"
  }
}
```

Here is the result in AWS Console:

[image]

[image]

If I delete and re-add the rule in the console, then the trigger appears on the lambda.

> It might be the case your lambda function that your topic uses is being created before the function.

I tested this also by tainting the topic rule alone so it got recreated (see the logs below). Unfortunately it didn't solve the issue.

```
An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
-/+ destroy and then create replacement

Terraform will perform the following actions:

-/+ module.lambda.aws_iot_topic_rule.rds_push (tainted) (new resource required)
      id:                             "dev_RdsPush" => <computed> (forces new resource)
      arn:                            "arn:aws:iot:eu-west-1:827689093226:rule/dev_RdsPush" => <computed>
      description:                    "Pushes events to a persistence lambda (rds store)" => "Pushes events to a persistence lambda (rds store)"
      enabled:                        "true" => "true"
      lambda.#:                       "1" => "1"
      lambda.1860721139.function_arn: "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:827689093226:function:RdsPersist-dev" => "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:827689093226:function:RdsPersist-dev"
      name:                           "dev_RdsPush" => "dev_RdsPush"
      sql:                            "SELECT * as payload, topic() as topic, timestamp() AS timestamp FROM '#' WHERE startswith(clientid(), 'dev-')" => "SELECT * as payload, topic() as topic, timestamp() AS timestamp FROM '#' WHERE startswith(clientid(), 'dev-')"
      sql_version:                    "2016-03-23" => "2016-03-23"


Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.
```

**Update: I just found a very similar issue at a different place:**

There's supposed to be an SNS subscription between this another lambda and a SNS. Here is the relevant code in the terraform:

```
resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "conference_call" {
  topic_arn = "${module.sns.conference_call_arn}"
  protocol  = "lambda"
  endpoint  = "${module.lambda.messaging_arn}"
}
```

(Obviously I checked the resources and they are correct)

In the console I don't see the trigger in the lambda but I do see the subscription in SNS:

[image]

[image]

**Update: exact same issue when creating the resources using AWS CLI**

```
# For the first issue
$ aws iot create-topic-rule --rule-name dev_RdsPush --topic-rule-payload '{"sql":"SELECT * as payload, topic() as topic, timestamp() AS timestamp FROM \'#\' WHERE startswith(clientid(), \'dev-\')","actions":[{"lambda":{"functionArn":"arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxx:function:RdsPersist-dev"}}]}'

# For the second issue
$ aws sns subscribe --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxx:conference-call-v1-dev --protocol lambda --notification-endpoint arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxx:function:Messaging-dev
```

---

**Solution:**

Add these:

IoT:

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "conference_call_sns" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromSNS"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.conference_call.function_name}"
  principal     = "sns.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "${var.conference_call_sns_arn}"
}
```

SNS:

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "messaging_sns" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromSNS"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.messaging.function_name}"
  principal     = "sns.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "${var.conference_call_sns_arn}"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a lambda permission to allow IoT to invoke lambda. The Lambda console uses the permissions of the function to show what can invoke it.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-rule-actions.html#lambda-rule.

Answer (score 2):

In my case this was the missing permission:

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "rds_topic_rule_permission" {
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.rds_persist.function_name
  principal     = "iot.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = aws_iot_topic_rule.rds_push.arn
}
```

See: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/24196#issuecomment-1103979956

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case your lambda function that your topic uses is being created before the function. Try adding `depends_on = ["aws_lambda_function.rds_persist"]` on your `aws_iot_topic_rule` and see how it goes.

Comment: I don't know if that counts but I had the same idea and to test this I tainted only the topic rule and it got recreated alone. But the lambda is still not linked properly.